# What's the meaning of "Maven projects do not use runtimes"

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee

When I convert my Java Web Project (with a runtime environment of Tomcat or so) from ordinary project to Maven project, it prompts **"Maven projects do not use runtimes"**. What's the meaning of it?

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of Maven is to support build activities by resolving build time dependencies. So, in a maven pom you should add all libraries required to complete successful build.

The runtime libraries are not required to perform a build and to setup runtime libraries there are other ways i.e. you can add them using project properties dialog box --> Targeted Runtimes.

you can refer to [this](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=228780) discussion which is relevant to your question.